# count unique object key in mule 4 dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

My requirement to count the unique Error message and it's count dynamically. Below I've added the input payload and the expected output. Please help to provide data weave for that.

Input:

```
  [
   {
    "Error": "Quote is Mandatory;"
   },
   {
    "Error": "Quote is Mandatory;"
   },
   {
    "Error": "OrderForm is canceled"
   },
   {
    "Error": "Dealer not found"
   }
  ]
```

Output:

```
    [
     {
      "Error": "Quote is Mandatory;",
      "count": 2
     },
     {
      "Error": "OrderForm is canceled",
      "count": 1
     },
     {
      "Error": "Dealer not found",
      "count": 1
     }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following. Here groupBy will used for grouping similar strings and then pluck will convert it to array and then you can iterate and count each nested array using sizeOf

dw

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload.Error groupBy $ pluck $) map(item)->{
    "Error" :item[0],
    "count": sizeOf(item)
}
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "Error": "Quote is Mandatory;",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "Error": "OrderForm is canceled",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "Error": "Dealer not found",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```